# How to execute 'show run' command through NAPALM

Tags: python, network-programming, paramiko

I am trying to learn use of napalm for Arista EOS automation. Here is the code that I am running :

```
import napalm
driver = napalm.get_network_driver('eos')
device = driver(hostname='127.0.0.1', username='vagrant',
                password='vagrant', optional_args={'port': 12443})

print('Opening ...')
device.open()

commands = ['show version', 'show configuration sessions', 'show ip interface brief']
res = device.cli(commands)
print(res)
```

The above code executes.
Now I am trying to add the command `show run` to the above list `commands`. As soon as I do that I get the following error :

```
pyeapi.eapilib.CommandError: Error [1002]: CLI command 2 of 2 'show run' failed: invalid command [incomplete token (at token 1: 'run')]
```

Please help me to execute the `show run` command through use of `napalm`

Answer (score 1):

The `cli` method takes a `list` of commands, you provided a string `'show run'`

```py
import napalm
driver = napalm.get_network_driver('eos')
device = driver(hostname='127.0.0.1', username='vagrant',
                password='vagrant', optional_args={'port': 12443})

print('Opening ...')
device.open()

commands = ['show run']
res = device.cli(commands)
print(res)
```

Answer (score 1):

My team just ran into this issue and banged our collective heads against the wall.

It appears that the EOS driver requires the non-abbreviated command. So when needing to get the output of 'show run', the command sent should actually be 'show running-config'.

Comment: 'show running-config' is still abbreviated, the non-abbreviated command is show running-configuration.  The way I read "incomplete token (at token 1: 'run')" is that Arista must have have another command, "show runXYYY..." where x is not 'n' (maybe "runXYYY..." is a filename?).  Try "show run?" and/or "show ") to check.

Answer (score 0):

You can get all outputs this way. I also recommend the TTP module apart from Napalm. An example is as follows.

```
import napalm
driver = napalm.get_network_driver('eos')
device = driver(hostname='127.0.0.1', username='vagrant',
            password='vagrant', optional_args={'port': 12443})

print('Opening ...')
device.open()

commands = ['show running-config','show configuration sessions', 'show ip 
interface brief']

for command in commands:
    res = device.cli(commands)
    print(res)
```

---

### ##TTP ##
[enter link description here](https://github.com/MertKulac/Parsing--Netmiko--TTP)